# Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache [in thread "Daemon worker"]

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

> Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache [in thread "Daemon worker"]

How do i fix this issue?It's a flutter code and it rends well in apk but when i try to builds bundle it give me this error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.